# How to add extra container to page header in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, luma-theme, containers

I am working on a new theme which is based on the Luma theme. I need to add a extra container to page header.my problem is that I can't identify how/where to add this.

Can anyone advise on what page i need to edit for this?

See the reference image

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Add a container `after="header.panel.wrapper"` inside
>   `header.container`. By the reference of the container add your template.

Inside your `default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.containertwo" as="header_containertwo" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="header-mini-container" after="header.panel.wrapper"/>
    </referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="header.containertwo">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mini.container" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
</page>
```

In the test.phtml

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;" id="test123"><p>This is a test</p></div>
```

Out put
[image]

**Sample module**

/app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.containertwo" as="header_containertwo" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="header-mini-container" after="header.panel.wrapper"/>
    </referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="header.containertwo">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mini.container" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
</page>
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;" id="test123"><p>This is a test </p></div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the default.xml located in Magento_theme/layout? Also where do I add the test.phtml to Magento_theme/template/html ?

Comment: OK, I've tried it and it's not showing...I've added it like this:       <referenceContainer name="header.containertwo">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mini.container" template="Vendor_Module::test123.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer> ... test123.html is in myTheme/Magento_theme/Templates directory...that right?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the "code" directory as mine is currently empty. For example my registration.php is in myVentor/myTheme/ directory. Do I still have to add these files to the code directory?

Comment: @user159500 would you please share with us as to what did you do exactly? I'm also confused about the "code" directory as I do not have it. Magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is

**Step one**: *Create a block in path*:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container"><block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" as="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/customheader.phtml" before="-"/>
```

**Step 2**: *Create phtml page path*:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/customheader.phtml

```
<h1>hello magento</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way:

1. Create a block in path:`app/design/frontend/Your_Vendor/Your_Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Content will be :

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container"><block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" as="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/customheader.phtml" before="-"/></referenceContainer>
```

2. Create custom.phtml page in
   path:app/design/frontend/Your_Vendor/Your_Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/customheader.phtml

content will be:

```
<h1>Your_Content_here</h1>
```