# How to add some custom content in magento header before welcome text

Tags: magento2, module, frontend

I want to add some content(a drop down) in header menu first item before welcome text message.

I have followed this answer [How to add extra container to page header in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136892/how-to-add-extra-container-to-page-header-in-magento-2)

It adds below the header. So I modified it by changing    `<referenceContainer name="header.container">` to    `<referenceContainer name="header.panel.wrapper">`

Now it is appearing in the header but below welcome text, sigin in links. I need to add it before Welcome text.

What is the change I need to make?

Comment: Are you try to want using layout or override core phtml file? Using Override core phtml file is simply.

Comment: I may also need to use a block, layout and template file.  @Rakesh

Comment: using phtml file is fit for you?

Comment: Ok. How to achieve it?

Comment: Just override  vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/customer.phtml file into your theme and you can keep your content before welcome message